# How to compare column1 from Df1 to column1 of different tables using Python(pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, automation, scripting

How to compare column1 from Df1 to column1 of different tables using Python (pandas)

- Df1 contains the result of a SQL statement (`select * from emp_table`)
- Df2 contains the result of a SQL statement (`select * from company_table`)

I am able to compare only 1 column from Df1 to 1 column of Df2. how to compare column1 of Df1 to column1 of Df3, Df4 etc

```
Df1 = df.column1
Df2 = df.column1

Df1.compare(Df2,keep_shape=True, keep_equal=True)
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am new to python

Since I can't upload sensitive data, I have created a sample table and columns. So, in the below snapshot, you can see Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4...Table 100 (there are many tables)

Now, I need to compare column1 of Table1 with Column1 of Table2, column1 of Table3 ... column1 of Table100.. in future tables might increase.

If the values of column matches then I need to mark it as pass or else fail

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some sample data of your dataframes as well as expected results?

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn - Since, I can't upload sensitive data, I have created a sample tables and columns where I need to compare column1 of table1 with column1 of table 2 and column1 of table3.... column1 of table100. Appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: Can you also post an expected result for the three tables you posted? Do you want one dataframe in the result? What should be the columns? Or do you want a dataframe per each comparison?